# como converter meu objeto em uma string?

Tags: banco-de-dados, string, orientação-a-objetos, query, inserir

Eu fiz uma função para inserir os dados no banco, porém como estou usando classes, eu tenho que inserir um objeto da classe no banco que vai conter os dados da pessoa em questão, só que a forma que ta sendo passados o objeto ta errado, pq não é uma string, acho que se eu converter em string ele vai salvar no banco a linha que precisa ser modificada tenho certeza que é somente a ultima, alguém por favor me ajuda, se tiverem disponibilidade de entrar em contato no skype com curse cmg, seria melhor ainda, pois aprenderia mais, é muito importante pra mim, estou fazendo meu trabalho de conclusão e preciso de um help.

```
include ('Pessoa.class.php');
include ('funcao_inserir.php');


$nome = $_REQUEST['nome'];  
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$numero_cartao_sus =$_REQUEST['numerodosus'];
$cpf = $_REQUEST['cpf'];
$rg = $_REQUEST["rg"];
$nomesocial = $_REQUEST["nomesocial"];
$nascimento = $_REQUEST["nascimento"];
$sexo = $_REQUEST["sexo"];
$pis_pasep = $_REQUEST["pis_pasep"];
$nome_mae = $_REQUEST["nome_mae"];
$nacionalidade = $_REQUEST["nacionalidade"];
$pais_nascimento = $_REQUEST["pais_nascimento"];
$municipio_nascimento =$_REQUEST["municipio_nascimento"];
$estado_nascimento =$_REQUEST["estado_nascimento"];
$telefone =$_REQUEST["telefone"];
$estado_civil =$_REQUEST["estado_civil"];
$orientacao_sexual =$_REQUEST["orientacao_sexual"];

$pessoa = new Pessoa();
$pessoa->setNome($nome);
$pessoa->setEmail($email);

$pessoa->setNumeroCartaoSus($numero_cartao_sus);
$pessoa->setCpf($cpf);
$pessoa->setRg($rg);
$pessoa->setNomesocial($nomesocial);
$pessoa->setNascimento($nascimento);
$pessoa->setSexo($sexo);
$pessoa->setPisPasep($pis_pasep);
$pessoa->setNomeMae($nome_mae);
$pessoa->setNacionalidade($nacionalidade);
$pessoa->setPaisNascimento($pais_nascimento);
$pessoa->setMunicipioNascimento($municipio_nascimento);
$pessoa->setEstadoNascimento($estado_nascimento);
$pessoa->setTelefone($telefone);
$pessoa->setEstadoCivil($estado_civil);
$pessoa->setOrientacaoSexual($orientacao_sexual);



inserir(array("nome","email"), $pessoa,"dados");
```

Answer (score 0):

A sua questão está muito mal formulada, e falta informação dos arquivo que você fez include pra eu conseguir entender exatamente o que está ocorrendo, mas vou tentar te ajudar a seguir o caminho correto com base no que você informou, vamos lá.

Você precisa executar um comando **INSERT**, então basicamente sua função inserir, vai precisar construir a **string** pra executar esse comando. No exemplo a seguir estou assumindo que seu banco de dados é **MySQL** e estou usando o mysqli do PHP:

```
<?php
    function inserir($tabela, $objeto){
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","usuario_db","senha_db","nome_db");

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $tabela . ' (';
        foreach ($objeto as $indice => $valor){
            $sql .= $indice . ',';
        }
        $sql = substr($sql,0,-1) . ') VALUES (';
        foreach ($objeto as $indice => $valor){
            $sql .= "'" . $valor . "',";
        }
        $sql = substr($sql,0,-1);
        $sql .= ')';

        $mysqli->query($sql);

        $linhasAfetadas = $mysqli->affected_rows;

        $mysqli->close();

        return $linhasAfetadas;
    }
?>
```

Nessa situação a função recebe o nome da tabela que deseja realizar o INSERT e o objeto com os campos correspondentes a tabela, montamos a string SQL do comando com estas informações usando **foreach** para percorrer o objeto, executamos o comando e encerramos a conexão com o banco, retornando opcionalmente no final o total de linhas que foram inseridas, assim você pode detectar que se foi inserida 1 linha o comando funcionou.

Vale ressaltar que essa solução não é perfeita, você precisaria tratar os dados que vão entrar nessa string, ainda mais no caso de campos de textos grandes, mas é o caminho que você precisa seguir.